# Divorce each other

Tags: word-usage

[This wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sasha_Agha)  contains the following sentence:

> "Her parents divorced each other when she was six or seven years old."

Is it necessary to say **each other** when the word *divorce* is used?

Couldn't it simply have said:

> "Her parents divorced when she was six or seven years old."

Comment: It could be.  And in my opinion it would sound better.  But I think *divorced each other* is also reasonable; it's possible to divorce someone.

Comment: Have you checked on usage (intransitivity etc) in a dictionary? [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/divorce) even gives your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the sentence works very well without "each other", I believe the author was influenced by the era before liberalized divorce. The 1960s will do as a general era, but the exact date varied from one USA state to another. I don't know when this occurred in the UK, which would be the relevant date for the article you cite.

Before that time, one generally said *John divorced Jane,* or *Jane divorced John,* depending on which party had filed the lawsuit. As it was necessary to supply a reason—usually adultery, which was taken more seriously then (especially, back then, when committed by the woman)—there tended to be a social judgment of blame.

They divorced *each other* indicates a divorce following modern practice, where divorce is more often than not a mutual decision, sometimes even with joint filing and a common attorney and predetermined property settlement.

Answer (score 0):

Omitting "each other" in this particular sentence is perfectly acceptable, but so is the original statement. In this case, it can be argued that including "each other" results in a pleonasm.